# Deleting session from one browser in second browser

Tags: php, session

For example In one browser (say in chrome) we run this code

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['login'] = "Jon";
```

Its possible to delete this session using other browser (say firefox)? that is, what code may run in firefox, for deleting  `$_SESSION['login']`, which value is `Jon` and which is started in chrome ?

Comment: It might be possible if you somehow clone the session cookie in Chrome and move it to Firefox.

Comment: I want make (for admin-panel) service, for deleting registered users. if admin want delete user `Jon` but `Jon` is currently active on site, how can admin unset  `Jon's` session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [`Passing the Session ID`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php) page. As long as the second browser passes the same ID as the first, you're effectively using the same session. I.e., yes you can do this, but you need to come up with some way for the second browser to get a hold of the session id that was created by the first.

Edit: To answer the second question asked in your follow-up comment, it depends on the session storage mechanism you use. If you're using a database table, then you'll probably have the userid as a field on that table, enabling you to also `DELETE FROM session WHERE userid = 'Jon'` when the userid is disabled.

Answer (score 2):

No, the `$_SESSION` is unique to the browser

Comment: No, it's unique to the session *id* -- which can be provided arbitrarily by any browser that knows it.

Answer (score 0):

The only way would be on the server side. You would have to figure out which sess_* file (on Ubuntu 12.04 these are found in /var/lib/php5) is associated with the Chrome browser and delete it.